# Is my shell broken?

Tags: posix, sh

```
#!/bin/sh
count=0
foo=0

echo "foo is $foo"

while [ "$foo" -eq 0 ] && [ "$count" -lt 10 ]; do
    echo "inside while: foo is $foo"
    count=$((count+1))
    foo=1
done

echo "after while"
```

You'd expect the script above to output the following, right?

```
foo is 0
inside while: foo is 0
after while
```

And it does on many other machines, like your own. But not mine ...

```
foo is 0
inside while: foo is 0
inside while: foo is 1
inside while: foo is 1
... (infinite loop)
```

Am I doing something wrong, or am I missing something obvious?

On this (broken?) machine, if I tweak the `while` conditional to use the "obsolescent" `-a` operator, it "fixes" the problem (whatever it is). Why?

Comment: First thing to investigate is what is kind of shell and version is your /bin/sh ? - and then investigate any of the startup scripts that's run when that shell starts.

Comment: ...that said -- as I suggested in your other question, would you consider using `set -x` to log individual commands as they run? I can actually think of a possible way hidden characters in your script could cause this behavior, and using `set -x` would make it clear if that were the case.

Comment: (Switching from `-eq` to `=` -- thus, making the comparison string-based rather than numeric -- would actually make you more robust against the failure mode I suspect).

Comment: ...running `sh -x yourscript` will, by the way, have the same behavior as putting a `set -x` just under the shebang; in any event, you'll get a precise log of all commands run. (Though now that I think of it, with some older / less-capable shells, those may not be escaped to make hidden characters visible, thus reducing the advantage; in that case, you might need to use `od`, `hexdump`, or similar).

Comment: It's interesting, by the way, that `count=$((count + 1))` works here; I would have initially guessed you were running a pre-POSIX Bourne shell, but that extension was added in POSIX sh.

Comment: @nos, there actually aren't many ways I can think of a startup script could result in the behavior at hand here. One could wrap/shadow `[`, but that's... not particularly probable; it would need to be an exceedingly deliberate act. And most of the other mechanisms are (1) non-POSIX (ie. debug traps), and (2) involve things that are turned off in noninteractive shells by default.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no hidden characters in your script text (an assumption I would suggest putting some effort into verifying!), this is indeed exhibiting behavior contrary to the POSIX sh standard.

> `n1 -eq n2` - True if the integers n1 and n2 are algebraically equal; otherwise, false.

Notably, this makes no specifications or guarantees about what happens if either argument is not in fact an integer; for instance, if it *would be* an integer, but has a carriage return or other nonprinting character on the end.

Other items to try, in order:

- Run `sh -x yourscript`, and look at the exact arguments called to `test` when running the loop. Also determine whether the second test in the `&&` chain is run at all.
- Change your operator from `-eq` to `=`, running a string comparison rather than a numeric comparison (and thereby ensuring that any string containing hidden characters will fail to compare successfully with the string `0`, rather than relying on undefined behavior in this case).
- Replace `[ "$foo" -eq 0 ]` with `false`, and ensure that the contents of the loop do not run (thus sanity-checking some other core parts of the shell's implementation).